# autopep8 in a git pre-commit -- how to automatically recommit?

Tags: git, bash, hook, pep8, pre-commit-hook

I have a git pre-commit hook that runs `autopep8` on touch python files.  My problem with it is that:
`# If there are whitespace errors,`it `print`s`the offending file names and fail`s`.` (see below.)

Question:

**How do I make it re-add and re-commit the files that I currently have to fix manually?**

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash


#
# An example hook script to verify what is about to be committed.
# Called by "git commit" with no arguments.  The hook should
# exit with non-zero status after issuing an appropriate message if
# it wants to stop the commit.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "pre-commit".

if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    against=HEAD
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

# If you want to allow non-ascii filenames set this variable to true.
allownonascii=$(git config hooks.allownonascii || echo false)

# Redirect output to stderr.
exec 1>&2

# Cross platform projects tend to avoid non-ascii filenames; prevent
# them from being added to the repository. We exploit the fact that the
# printable range starts at the space character and ends with tilde.
if [ "$allownonascii" != "true" ] &&
    # Note that the use of brackets around a tr range is ok here, (it's
    # even required, for portability to Solaris 10's /usr/bin/tr), since
    # the square bracket bytes happen to fall in the designated range.
    test $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A -z $against |
      LC_ALL=C tr -d '[ -~]\0' | wc -c) != 0
then
    echo "Error: Attempt to add a non-ascii file name."
    echo
    echo "This can cause problems if you want to work"
    echo "with people on other platforms."
    echo
    echo "To be portable it is advisable to rename the file ..."
    echo
    echo "If you know what you are doing you can disable this"
    echo "check using:"
    echo
    echo "  git config hooks.allownonascii true"
    echo
    exit 1
fi

# If there are whitespace errors, print the offending file names and fail.
git diff-index --check --cached $against --

touched_python_files=`git diff --cached --name-only |egrep '\.py$' || true`
if [ -n "$touched_python_files" ]; then
    autopep8 \
        --ignore=E26 \
        --in-place \
        --jobs=0 \
        --max-line-length=150 \
        $touched_python_files
fi
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do with same thing with astyle...

Comment: sorry not yet... could wrap this script with another one, checking for any output, doing a reset --soft and then recommitting with the same message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a modified version of @steven's script.

If `autopep8` modifies a file the commit is stopped (so you can commit partial diffs with `git add -p` without worries). The commit is also stopped if `autopep8` fails for some reason.

Unfortunately there's no way to tell from exit status or output if `autopep8` modified something, so it has to run twice (once for the diff, once for the edit).

```
#!/bin/sh

status=0
touched_python_files=$(git diff --cached --name-only | grep -E '\.py$')
if [ -n "$touched_python_files" ]; then
    options="\
      --ignore=E26 \
      --max-line-length=150 \
    "

    output=$(autopep8 -d $options "${touched_python_files[@]}")
    status=$?

    if [ -n "$output" ]; then
        autopep8 -i -j 0 $options "${touched_python_files[@]}"
        echo ">>> autopep8 edited some files <<<"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

exit $status
```

Comment: great!  can you edit the script so it runs twice then?

Comment: I'm some years late but... we need to run run twice `autopep8`, not the script (and indeed you'll find twice `autopep8` in the code)

Comment: For anybody that uses ```git commit -a``` to commit all modified files without caching remove the ```--cached``` option from line 4.

Comment: Not sure what version it became available, but autopep8 has an `--exit_code` option that will return `2` if there is a difference.